# Is there a way to log IP for FTP uploads in Redhat?

Tags: shell-script, rhel, ip, sftp

Is there a way to log which IP-address uploads files through sFTP in Redhat? The users sign in with SSH, so I can see their IP's in /var/log/secure.

But is there a log for the built in sFTP-server, so I can see either what username or what IP uploaded each file, or is there a way to monitor this?

I already have incrond to run a script when a file in the sFTP folder is changed, but this is run on the user owning the files, and doesn't know which user changed it.

I don't know what the standard sFTP client is called, but perhaps there is some other standard sFTP-server that has more logging than this one?

Comment: duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/73319/sftp-logging-is-there-a-way

Comment: Be consistent. In title you write FTP, while elsewhere you write SFTP. FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols with different deamons and logs. And why "sFTP" - lowercase "s"?

Comment: I guess since this question is duplicate, should I remove it? sFTP, not sure, thought it was written that way. :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>I found no option in `internal-sftp` to force log.</s>

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, use

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f  USER -l INFO
```

then use syslog.conf to trap USER.INFO file in a custom file.

in `/etc/syslog.conf`

```
user.info /var/log/my-sftp.log
```

as mention [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1114958/which-internal-sftp-options-are-available), you can use either `internal-sftp` or

```
/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```